# Javascript backtick string interpolation creates a URL with blank spaces

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

When using string interpolation with backticks to create an URL which posts to a django endpoint, the created url adds unnecessary whitespace and a new line.

The faulty js in question:

```
(function (window, document, undefined){

    // Upvote / Downvote selectors:
    const upvote = document.getElementById('upvote');
    const downvote = document.getElementById('downvote');
    const object_id = document.getElementById('object_id').textContent;
    // const object_id = document.getElementById('object_id').innerHTML;

    // csrftoken getter
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    // Voting function

    const vote = ($route) => {
        fetch(`/${$route}/${object_id}/`, {
            method:'post',
            headers:{
              'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
              'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
              'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData);
          return responseData;
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));
    }

    // Event listener adder
    const add = ($element, $route) => {
        $element.addEventListener('click', vote.bind(null, $route))
    }

    add(upvote, "upvote")
    add(downvote, "downvote")

})(window, document);
```

When I hardcode the URL, it completes successfully:

```
function vote_up(){
    fetch(`/upvote/3/`, {
        method:'post',
        headers:{
          'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
          'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
          'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData);
          return responseData;
      })
      .catch(error => console.warn(error));
}
```

The error message:

```
Fetch failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/upvote/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%203%20%20%20%20/".
```

In this case, the id of the object being handled by the django view function is 3. The number is present, so the string interpolation is at least partly successful.

This is the django view function:

```
def vote_action(user, instance, upvote_or_downvote):
    try:
        upvote_or_downvote.vote(user, instance, upvote_or_downvote())
        return JsonResponse({"success":True}, status = 200)
    except IntegrityError:
        return JsonResponse({'success':False}, status = 200)

@require_POST
def upvote(request, id = None):
    picture = get_object_or_404(Picture, id = id)
    user = request.user
    return vote_action(user, picture, Upvote)

@require_POST
def downvote(request, id = None):
    picture = get_object_or_404(Picture, id = id)
    user = request.user
    return vote_action(user, picture, Upvote)
```

Comment: The `.textContent` may have all sorts of spaces in it, and you're not doing anything to get rid of them.

Comment: I have also tried innerHTML which gives the same result. Is there a third way to grab the content of a div? Also, how would I go about getting rid of the whitespaces in .textContent?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `.textContent` but you'll have to explicitly get rid of the spaces. Probably `.textContent.trim()` is enough, or you could do it with a regular expression and `.replace()`.

Comment: trim() was the ticket. However, I can't accept the answer since it's a comment.

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate, but I'm terrible at finding those so I'll type in a quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers generally ignore whitespace at the beginning and end of text in a text node, but `.textContent` will give the whitespace back to you anyway. Thus you can use

```
const object_id = document.getElementById('object_id').textContent.trim();
```

to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace. In your case that's probably all you need, but more generally you can get rid of all whitespace with

```
const object_id = 
  document.getElementById('object_id').textContent.replace(/\s+/g, "");
```